# highliting cells that fit a given condition in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to highlight the cells which meet the condition:

> compare all the values in the group with the final value (for that group)
> if that difference is > 3% highlight green
> if it's less than -3% highlight red

I want to do it for a varying amount of groups of different sizes. Here's an example

[image: output].

It's easy to do manually, but for a much larger dataset I'd like to not have to do it one by one.

I just found out **openpyxl** exists, so not sure if that's even the way to go. Also, I have 0 VBA experience so I'm hoping python is the way, but open to suggestions.

I've managed to do the math using pandas, but I can't change the cell colors that way so I'm stuck.

Comment: Use conditional formatting.

Comment: @moken I've tried conditional formatting but the amount of values in each group varies so I'd have to do each section separately and that's slower than doing the mental math. My goal is to find the row that has the "final" value then compare the rest of the values above it and format accordingly. Even if it's 1 or 100.  Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

On another read I believe I better understand what you goal is.

As indicated you can do this with conditional formatting the code can separate each group to perform the necessary calc on that group only.

In this case based on your example image; the code determines each of the three group ranges and implements the a formula to calculate the differences against the appropriate 'final' cell value and apply the necessary fill colour, Green and Red for each.

This code applies 6 rules for conditional formatting on the sheet.

The resultant sheet is per your image except the cell in the 'value' column next to 'c2' i.e. '-7.00%'. This cell is also highlighted in Red as its -18.60% different to 11.60%.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import fills
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule


def create_cf(letter, start_cell, end_cell):

    ### Create range for the group, from 'range+top' to one row less than the final cell
    cf_range = f'{letter}{start_cell}:{letter}{end_cell-1}'
    ### Create a dict of the conditional formatting formula and colour to go with it
    ### Two colour criteria Green and Red
    colouring_range = {f'(${letter}${end_cell}-${letter}{start_cell})<=-0.03':'00FF00',
                       f'(${letter}${end_cell}-${letter}{start_cell})>=0.03':'FF0000'}

    ### Loop the dictionary and apply criteria and colour to the group range
    for criteria, fill_color in colouring_range.items():
        ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                         FormulaRule(
                                             formula=[criteria],
                                             fill=fills.PatternFill("solid", bgColor=fill_color),
                                             stopIfTrue=False
                                             )
                                         )
path = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

final_search = 'final'  ## Search word to find the range and calc cell
range_top = 1           ## First cell in the group range (offset by 1)
values_col = 'B'        ## 'Value' Column letter
### Iterate columns A looking for the 'final' search word (starting @ row 2)
for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        cv = cell.value
        cr = cell.row
        ### If cell is empty we don't want to search the value, also use to increment the top of the range row number
        if cv is None:
            range_top = cr
            continue
        ### If the search word is in the cell then use as calc cell and range end
        elif final_search in cv:
            final_cell = cr
            ### Call create_cf to create the conditional format
            create_cf(values_col, range_top+1, final_cell)

wb.save(path)
```

###-------Alternate Code-----##
If you don't want to use conditional formatting and instead make the updates static;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

greenfill = PatternFill(start_color='00FF00', end_color='00FF00', fill_type="solid")
redfill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type="solid")


def update_background(current_cell, start_cell, end_cell, range_difference):

    final_value = current_cell.offset(row=0, column=1).value
    ### Use cell offsets to find get the cell values in the group range
    for i in range(1, end_cell-start_cell):
        row_offset = end_cell-(start_cell+i)
        compare_value = current_cell.offset(row=-row_offset, column=1).value
        ### Calc the difference between final and current cells
        calc_difference = final_value - compare_value

        ### Based on difference fill background colour
        if calc_difference >= range_difference:
            current_cell.offset(row=-row_offset, column=1).fill = redfill
        elif calc_difference <= -range_difference:
            current_cell.offset(row=-row_offset, column=1).fill = greenfill


path = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

final_search = 'final' ## Search word to find the range and calc cell
range_top = 1          ## First cell in the group range (offset by 1)
difference = 0.03      ## Compare difference value

for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
        cv = cell.value
        cr = cell.row
        ### If cell is empty we don't want to search the value, also use to increment the top of the range row number
        if cv is None:
            range_top = cr
            continue
        ### If the search word is in the cell then use as calc cell and range end
        elif final_search in cv:
            final_cell = cr
            ### Call function to check and update cells within the group range
            update_background(cell, range_top, final_cell, difference)

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```